# Trying to separate text in columns

Tags: multicol, urls

I am trying to get this URL to drop off nicely as it looks off. I have tried seperating the columns further with     \column sep but it doesnt work

```
 \documentclass[oneside,12pt]{article}
 \usepackage{multicol}
  \setlength{\columnsep}{2cm}
  \usepackage{url}

 \begin{document}
  \section{Section}
   \subsection*{sub section}
  \begin{multicols}{2}
   \noindent
   Mr Joe Blogs- Person
   \\Level 1 Cordelias Street
 [![enter image description here][1]][1]\\Australia 
 \\Email:\url{Joe Blogsn@the email is long.com}
 \\\\
 \columnbreak

 \noindent
 Jim - Person
 \\Level 1 Cordelias Street
 \\Australia
 \\Email: \url{Joeblogs@reallylong.com}
 \end{multicols}
  \pagebreak
  \end{document}
```

[image]

**any help would be greatly appreciated**

Comment: Try \raggedright.  (That or \sloppy are SOP for narrow columns.)